# Unable to remove Navigation Bar when TabView is used inside the Navigation View - SwiftUI - iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, ios15

**SwiftUI View Hierarchy**
Navigation View --> VStack --> Custom SearchView --> TabView

In the view, with the hierarchy mentioned above, I'm unable to remove navigation bar. It's visibility is successfully changed with the code mentioned shared below.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
func iOS15UIBarSpecs(){
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    
    navBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navBarAppearance.shadowImage = nil
    navBarAppearance.shadowColor = nil
        
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

The presence of this navigation bar is blocking tap gestures on any view coming behind it.

The same view was working fine in iOS 14 with the following line of code.

```
  .navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think the better issue to address is "I'm unable to remove navigation bar." Please can you show the code that creates this view and how you are trying to hide the navigation bar?

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of this... https://filipmolcik.com/how-to-hide-swiftui-navigationbar/ ?

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister , I edited my question.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example for the question sot hat we can see the same error you're seeing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: getting same issue, able  to remove navigation bar in iOS14 but not in iOS 15

Comment: Did anyone find solution for this?

Comment: Facing the same issue in iOS 15